# Difference between Pesik Reshe Delo Niha Le, Pesik Reshe Delo Ichpat Le, & Melacha She'en Sarich LeGufa

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, lomdus, kavana-intent, pesik-reisha

What is the practical difference between actions considered *Pesik Reshe Delo Niha Le*, *Pesik Reshe Delo Ichpat Le*, and *Melecha She'en Sarich Legufa*? What is an example that can demonstrate the difference between the three?

(Sources, of course [see the Rashash on Tosafot Ketuvot 6a])

Comment: According to Tosafos (*Shabbos* 103a, s.v. *lo tz'richa*), there is no difference between פסיק רישא דלא ניחא ליה and פסיק רישא דלא איכפת ליה. Rashi's position is less clear. See [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A7_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%90#.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.98.D7.99_.D7.94.D7.93.D7.99.D7.9F) for a brief overview of opinions. Regardless, *p'sik reisha* involves an incidental but unavoidable *m'lacha* that occurs as a result of an activity, while *m'lacha she'eina tz'richa l'gufa* involves a non-incidental *m'lacha* which is the basis for an activity...

Comment: ... but that was not performed for the same type of purpose as that *m'lacha* was performed in the *mishkan*. For example, digging a hole to get dirt rather than to create a furrow would be *eina t'zricha l'gufa* but still *nicha leih*. This is an oversimplification of the topic, so hopefully someone will post a proper, thorough answer.

Comment: IIRC Reb Chaim touches on this in Hilchot Shabbat 10:17

Comment: "the practical difference": do you mean the difference in the person's action (which action is considered _enah t'zricha l'gufah_ and which is _p'sik resha_) or the difference in law (what the level of prohibition of a _m'lacha sheenah t'zricha l'gufah_ is and what the level of prohibition of a _p'sike resha_ is)?

Comment: @msh210 in the actual action.

Comment: @SethJ My pleasure. Thanks for your holy contributions to the site!

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9135/369 though its a little *more* complicated!

Comment: https://din.org.il/2018/06/26/%D7%94%D7%91%D7%93%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A7-%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%90-%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%97%D7%90-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%A4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Hilchos Shabbos 1:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbath.1.7?lang=bi) of the Mishnah Torah,  [The Kesef Mishna](https://www.sefaria.org/Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbath.1.7.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) brings HaRav Avraham Hachasid (Rambam's son) and explains *psik reisha* doesn't need the actual melacha, he brings the case of closing a door on a deer.By *melacha shaina tzricha* it is the melacha you want but not its purpose, ayin sham.

Comment: I dont know why you all call it psik raisho. The correct term is dovor shaino miscavain which as you correctly say he is not 'mechavain' for the m'locho.

Comment: @annex did you see the source?

Comment: No, but while youre at it. Is misaseik for which one is potur a maase aveira or not. If one east matsa as misaseik is one yotsai since if one eats 'cheilev' one is chayev. If the 'hano'oh' makes it into a maase then maybe he is. If it is a maaseh anyway only potur when there is no hanooh. Then just because he is chayev with a hanooh it doesnt follow that with matsa, a mitsva, he is yotsai.

Comment: It comes into present daf yomi psochim. The question being why must one search for chomets. If he has any its no worse than misasaik.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I was looking for but you could have explained a little better in my opinion.

Comment: @hacham Gabriel ,how so? Even after the explanation it is a concept in shas which is very hard to distinguish.I rem learning a tosdos who brings the Aruch who explains it one way but the Ran another way.

Comment: In reference to shabbas 103 ,tosfos there

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments  פסיק רישא דלא ניחא ליה is probably equivalent to פסיק רישא דלא איכפת ליה. The Big Question is regular פסיק רישא vs. מלאכה שאינה צריכה לגופה

**Background**
There is double machlokes that comes up between R.Shimon and R. Yehuda. R.Shimon holds "דבר שאינו מתכוון is muttar ([Beitza 2:10](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%99)), while R.Yehuda holds its assur. R. Shimon holds מלאכה שאינה צריכה לגופה is assur (rabbinically) while R.Yehuda holds it d'oraysa.

**The Categories**
**דבר שאינו מתכוון** - when you do one act, and another secondary action also takes place. E.g. if you drag a light bench to bring somewhere, and it might cause a furrow to be dug, (the melahca of plowing). The shulchan aruch et.al. hold this is muttar (like R.Shimon), even if the secondary act is beneficial.

A **פסיק רישא** is a davar sh'eino miskavein where the secondary act is for sure going to happen. E.g. if you drag a heavy bench somewhere, and it will definitely cause a furrow to be dug (which is also beneficial). This is forbidden even according to R. Shimon, and many views hold it is assur d'oraysa.

A   **פסיק רישא דלא ניחא ליה** is simply a **פסיק רישא** where the secondary act is not beneficial (or worse). For example, if you get no benefit from the furrow your bench creates. While there were some who permitted this, most hold it is rabbinically forbidden (see שו"ע או"ח סימן שכ:יח).

The standard case of **מלאכה שא"צ לגופה** is if you blow out a candle to make the room dark, but not to get ashes (the purpose of the melacha in the mishkan). I.e. you do a melacha but not לגופה, for its "purpose".  The Shulchan aruch et.al. again hold like R.Shimon, though some (the Rambam) hold like R.Yehudah.

**Complexities**
**מלאכה שא"צ לגופה**  also comes up when you dig to get dirt, but it results in a hole being built (melacha of boneh). This leads to various complexities and there are many different interpretations on how it differs from פסיק רישא.
According to a standard explanation, when you do an action (digging) for a different purpose (getting dirt) we can show its in a different form than the melacha in the mishkan, but when you do a different action (dragging a bench), you're intent no longer matters, and it may be d'oraysa (of plowing). There are still some difficulties, so there are other explanations and divisions between d'oraysa and derabanan.

Answer (score 1):

*I based this off one of the Aharonim I just don't remember right now which Aharon (I think it was the Rashash Ketuvot 6a).*

By Melacha Sheen Sarich Legufa: the actual action is a Melacha even if you don't want to do the Melacha it is inevidble because the action itself is a Melacha.

By Pesik Reshe Delo Niha Le: The action itself isnt a Melacha but there is an inevidble Melacha that comes along with it.

*Now this is based off a few other Mefarshim:*

Pesik Reshe Delo Niha Le- is that he specifically doesn't want the Melacha that is occuring to occur because it's unncessary but it is inevidable

Pesik Reshe Delo Ichpat Le- he doesn't care if it happens but it is inevidable.