# Is dvar sheina mitchaven permitted if the melacha is inevitable?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, kavana-intent, pesik-reisha

My question refers to the class of permitted actions that may inadvertently cause melachas as byproducts. (For example, with hair brushing, the intention is not to pull out the hair, but this does often occur by accident; thus the melacha of shearing is performed inadvertently.)

I had thought that such actions were permitted on Shabbos so long as a byproduct melacha was not inevitable, and that in cases where the melacha is inevitable--such as hair brushing--the action is prohibited.

However, I have encountered [one](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XLQeOQ95HFgJ:download.yutorah.org/2014/1053/813405.pdf%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) source that says, rather confusingly, "The halacha is that a dvar sheina mitchaven is completely permitted." Does this mean that dvar sheina mitchaven is permitted even if a resulting melacha is inevitable, and is that correct?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28904/difference-between-pesik-reshe-delo-niha-le-pesik-reshe-delo-ichpat-le-melac

Comment: I think I learned a better approach to this question: If a melacha is non-inevitable AND it's not your intention to do the melacha /get the result of the melacha, you can do the thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An excerpt from the source you linked:

> Dvar sheina mitchaven:  Doing  a  permitted  action  in  a  way  in  which  one  doesn’t  intend  for  a  melacha  to  occur  as  a  byproduct  of  one’s  intended  action  is  considered  a  dvar  sheina mitchaven. Nonetheless, when it is inevitable that amelacha will  take  place  as  a  result  of  one’s  inherently  permissible  action,  that  action  becomes  forbidden  (see  Pesik  Reisha).  For  example,  dragging  a  light  chair  in  a  field  where  one’s  intent  is  to  transport  the  chair  would  be  a  dvar  sheinamitchaven when the furrow is created as one did not intend to create a furrow.7 Tosfot (Shabbos 75a s.v. mitasek) writesthat dvar sheina mitchaven is not unique to Shabbos; rather, it is a general exemption found in numerous laws throughoutthe Torah. There is a dispute between Rabbi Yehuda and Rabbi Shimon whether performing an action that is a dvar sheinamitchaven is permitted or forbidden. Within the opinion that is forbidden, many assume that it is only a rabbinicprohibition on Shabbos.8 The halacha is that a dvar sheina mitchaven is completely permitted.9

When it is inevitable, it is no longer termed a "dvar sheina mitchaven" and enters a category called "pesik reisha" which is prohibited.  A "regular" dvar sheina mitchaven" is permitted.

Comment: Just beat me to it.

Comment: @Scimonster fastest gun in the west. :-) (not really - I'm usually pretty slow)

Comment: Yup, that's why i don't have another 500 rep on SO...

Comment: Thanks to both of you... I did read that part of the source, but needed your last comment to clarify.