# How do we determine what is inevitable enough to be a Psik Reisha?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, melacha-creative-work

Regarding a [psik reisha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23529/what-exactly-is-psik-reisha), my earlier [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56206/is-a-psik-reisha-dlo-nicha-or-dlo-echpat-judged-against-a-communal-standard) focused on whether the resultant action is judged according to a standard, but I am also unclear about what determines the "inevitable" nature of the outcome.

If you cut the head off of a chicken, it will most [probably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_the_Headless_Chicken) die. If you drag a heavy bench through soft ground, it will make a furrow. But through less hard ground, the act might [not](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-09-05/) lead to an [inevitable](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/is-dvar-sheina-mitchaven-permitted-if-the-melacha-is-inevitable) furrowing melacha.

How does one determine the line between "it will" and "it might not"?

To wit, I received an email with halachot (Dirshu, 8 Nisan) which reads

> A person may not comb his hair on Shabbos because it is a psik reisha (inevitable) that hair will be removed. It is even forbidden to use a comb to move hairs into place without really combing them, because hairs also get pulled out that way.

The followup halacha reads

> A soft brush may be used on Shabbos if it is not a psik reisha that hair will be removed. **If it is inevitable that hairs will be removed by brushing,** the brush should not be used for regular brushing but may be used to align the hair.

(Bold added)

I comb my hair with a comb every day and have precious little hair left so I stay very conscious every thing that gets pulled out, and my comb doesn't do the damage. How was it determined that the comb is a priori invalid -- what measure of inevitability was satisfied? Is it a personal standard (may I use a comb whereas someone else can't) or is universally derived and applied?

Comment: The Rivash about combing is saying that while any particular stroke through your hair won't for sure pull out a hair, the multiple strokes needed to comb your hair will certainly remove at least one hair. If that doesn't apply to your head and brush then so be it. It is a bit of a Chiddush. The Gemara talks about a Nazir combing his hair and if Psik Reishei applies so that'll be your primary source

Comment: halevai my hair needed multiple strokes...

Comment: psik raisho is a very difficult subject. Rashi in zevochim 91 says for instance if one can do it without a psik raisho then one can do it with.