# Nest Thermostat and shabbat

Tags: shabbat, technology

I'd like to know if a [Nest Thermostat](https://nest.com/thermostat/meet-nest-thermostat/) would be allowed by halacha? They say it programs itself and it realizes when you come home, so when you come home on shabbat, the machine will detect it, and it will adjust itself accordingly.

I don't own this machine, but maybe there would be an option for it to only work on a schedule on certain days, which would solve this issue totally. But let's say there's no option; what would be the halacha?

Comment: The web site implies that the motion detector is built in and cannot be turned off. If this is true, then it cannot be used on Shabbos.

Comment: @sabbahillel If the motion sensor cannot be turned off but the functionality that works based on the readings of the motion sensor _can_ be turned off, then it's not so simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smart thermostat on Shabbos - what should one do?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51231/smart-thermostat-on-shabbos-what-should-one-do)

Comment: I agree with @Daniel I just couldn't find it earlier.

Comment: @Daniel Since I could not find the details of that on the site, I could not say. I would agree that it is similar to the question that you ppoint to, but here the question is, can one turn off the motion detector functionality. Also even if it does not change the temperature setting does it have a light on the device that goes on and off based on the motion detector?

Comment: @sabbahillel No the question here is "But let's say there's no option; what would be the halacha?"