# Triggering motion sensors on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, electricity

I thought it was forbidden to walk in front of a motion sensor on Shabbat  But I read that Rabbi Shmuel Wosner allows it, because your intention is not to trigger the sensor [Shevet Halevi 9:69].  Is his responsum generally accepted or is it still a matter of dispute?  I know people who will stay in their apartment on Shabbat because the owner refuses to turn off his motion sensors.

Comment: What does the motion sensor do?

Comment: Turns a light on, opens a door -- triggers electricity.

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-17-14/  Turning on a light where it helps you see, would be more problematic than general electricity (I.e. video etc)

Comment: https://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=4485

Comment: Does this answer the question? - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4219/27180

Comment: @Chatzkel Even where it doesn't help you see, turning on an incandescent bulb is a clear melacha (setting aside the question of intent), as opposed to electricity in general.

Comment: The question of intent is the central topic, so you can’t really set it aside